# Does mysql subquery always use a temporary table? that can't be indexed

Tags: mysql, select

Just want to make sure I am understanding this right. If I have huge data sets and the structure of database is such that I have to do

> SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...) AS tmp

does this mean that the query will always be slow and there is no way to fix this by adding some indexes, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not... its based on indexes and optimization techniques.  Build your queries and help the indexes based on smallest granularity that you data is most likely to be queried by.  Example... if you have a table of orders, you could have the query based on date of the order, or customer.  However, if you ever want to query orders by customer within a date range, the better index to utilize would be by (customerID, orderDate) instead of (orderDate, Customer).

The first index would jump right to the customer in question at the closest date range you are looking for and go to the end of that date range and be done.

The second index would have to go through each date in your range (which would have many customers to skip over), then get records for the one customer, then go to the next date and do it all over again.

Comment: Doesn't seem to address the question at all? In SQL Server when doing a `SELECT` from a derived table or a view the optimiser expands the derived table definition out and can push the predicates down and use indexes. As far as I understood it the OP is asking will it always get materialised into a non indexed temporary table in MySQL.

Comment: @MartinSmith, it actually DOES.. per "...does this mean that the query will always be slow..."

Comment: I was probably more interested in the title question "Does mysql subquery always use a temporary table? that can't be indexed". Supposing a table `foo` with composite index on `col1,col2` how will MySQL evaluate `SELECT * FROM (SELECT col1,col2 FROM foo WHERE col1 = 2) AS tmp WHERE col2=3`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to read some literature about index because it helps to understand how your structure works, how your indexes are stored and what its position with its referenced value. In MySQL they are basically 3 structure types B-Tree, Hash, R-TRee. Every different engine (MyISAM, InnoDB, NDB) has their own index performance nuances for example NDB engine has B-tree index but in reality it works like T-tree. Data types are also very considerable. If you use different type index won't work or it will slow down some query performance. So talking about joins their performance are based on decisions made up from earlier phase that is what i told earlier.